# what does FlatLoop/UnFlatLoop mean in valueinjecter?

Tags: .net, mapper, valueinjecter

here is the valueinjecter doc(http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/documentation), but i'm not so

clear about these terms, flattening/unflattening ,FlatLoop/UnFlatLoop ... , how could i

understand these easier ?

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flatloop will do this:

```
flat.InjectFrom<FlatLoopValueInjection>(unflat);

//same as doing
flat.HeythereHowareYou = unflat.Hey.ther.How.are.You

flat.abcde = unflat.abc.d.e
```

and unflat the other way around

```
unflat.InjectFrom<UnflatLoopValueInjection>(flat);

//same as doing
unflat.very.big.object.nesting = flat.verybigobjectnesting

unflat.a.b.c.d.e = flat.abcde
```

hope you'll like my way of explaining things :)

Comment: automapper had flattening, did that, after when did it the other way around I had to come up with a name, first thinking of deflattening, after thought that unflat might be better

Comment: indeed , i'm asking the definition of flat/unflat , hha